# How to add a comment box below Shipping method in Checkout page

Tags: magento

I wanted to add a comment box and submit button, below shipping method, in Checkout page.

In which file, I have to edit the code?

Comment: which magento version that you are using ?

Answer (score 1):

Step: – 1
Add Custom Field into Billing Address tab of the Onepage Checkout in Frontend.

```
app\design\frontend\[Package_name]\[Theme_name]\template\checkout\onepage\payment\methods.phtml
```

Add code below:

```
<li class="wide">
<label for="shipnew"><?php echo $this->__('New field') ?></label>
<div class="input-box">
<input type="text" id="shipnew" name="shipnew" value="" title="<?php echo $this->__('Ship Title') ?>" class="input-text" />
</div>
</li>
```

Then follow:

http://excellencemagentoblog.com/magento-add-custom-fields-checkout-page